# Calculate the sum of column values per row but not include every value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, sum

So I have this dataset which looks like this.

| id | something | number1 | number2 | number3 | number4 | number5 | number6 | sum_columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 105 | 1 | NaN | NaN | 2 | 3 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 300 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 33 | 6 | 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 20 | 1 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 5 | 3 | 3 |

Now I need to calculate the sum of columns values  starting with 'number' but only include the values that are in range of 1-5.

So the final dataset would look like this:

| id | something | number1 | number2 | number3 | number4 | number5 | number6 | sum_columns | sum_values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 105 | 1 | NaN | NaN | 2 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 10 |
| 2 | 300 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 33 | 6 | 2 | 6 | 6 |
| 3 | 20 | 1 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 5 | 3 | 3 | 9 |

I know I can calculate the sum of columns containing number like this:

```
df['values_sum']=df.filter(like='number').sum(axis=1)
```

But how to include only values in columns that are in range of 1-5 is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for filter values less like `6` and replace not matched to `0`:

```
df1 = df.filter(like='number')
df['values_sum'] = df1.where(df1.lt(6),0).sum(axis=1)

#if need values only range(1,6)
#df['values_sum'] = df1.where(df1.isin(range(1, 6)),0).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   id  something  number1  number2  number3  number4  number5  number6  \
0   1        105        1      NaN      NaN      2.0        3        4   
1   2        300        2      1.0      1.0     33.0        6        2   
2   3         20        1      NaN      NaN      NaN        5        3   

   sum_columns  values_sum  
0            4        10.0  
1            6         6.0  
2            3         9.0
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad English, I edited the question so it would be easier to understand. Basically I need to count the sum of all number columns but not include the values that are out of the range of 1-5

Comment: This seemed to work, thank you!